# How can I triplicate an item in an array loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array

```
var array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...]
```

I want to get  each number repeated three times in a loop, such as

```
var newarray = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6...]
```

How can I do it? Thank you!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to return an array with the element repeated thrice for each item and then flatten it by one level.

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
const result = array.flatMap(x => [x, x, x])
console.log(result)
```